# User input is not shown in canvas and no image is produced

Tags: javascript, html, image, text, dynamic-programming

I want to create a text to image convertor webpage. Hence, i am using canvas but i am not able to get the user input in the canvas to create an image of it.
Please suggest any other way to create a text to image convertor.

Cannot get the input to canvas

```js
function addText() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.font = "10px Georgia";
  var ele = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
  var ele1 = document.getElementById("ageInput").value;
  var ele2 = document.getElementById("diesInput").value;
  if (ele.textContent) {
    context.fillText(ele, 10, 90);
    context.fillText(ele1, 10, 110);
    context.fillText(ele2, 10, 130);
  }
}

function exportImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById("exportedImage");
  img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Details</header>
  <br/>
  <label>Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="nameInput" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
  <br/>
  <label>Age</label>
  <input type="number" id="ageInput" placeholder="Enter your age" required>
  <br/>
  <label>Diesease</label>
  <input type="text" id="diesInput" placeholder="Enter diesease name shown" required>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" id="insertTxt" onclick="addText()">Add details</button>
  <div class="imageshowing">
    <h2>Preview</h2>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border: solid 1px gray;">
            </canvas>
    <br/>
    <h2>Exported Image</h2>
    <img id="exportedImage" width="200" height="200" src="#" />
    <br/>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" id="convertor" onclick="exportImage()">Export canavas to image</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
```

`ele` is a string which is what is typed in the name input.

And then there's:

```
if (ele.textContent) {
```

`ele.textContent` therefore is undefined, because a string does not have a `textContent` parameter.

Change that to:

```
if ("" !== ele) {
```

...to test for something other than an empty string.

```js
function addText() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.font = "10px Georgia";
  var ele = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
  var ele1 = document.getElementById("ageInput").value;
  var ele2 = document.getElementById("diesInput").value;

  if ("" !== ele) { // <-- make sure name input is not an empty string

    context.fillText(ele, 10, 90);
    context.fillText(ele1, 10, 110);
    context.fillText(ele2, 10, 130);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Details</header>
  <br/>
  <label>Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="nameInput" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
  <br/>
  <label>Age</label>
  <input type="number" id="ageInput" placeholder="Enter your age" required>
  <br/>
  <label>Diesease</label>
  <input type="text" id="diesInput" placeholder="Enter diesease name shown" required>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" id="insertTxt" onclick="addText()">Add details</button>
  <div class="imageshowing">
    <h2>Preview</h2>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border: solid 1px gray;"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```